# Prestashop : How to change currency symbol position left to right

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, price, currency-formatting

How to display price currency symbol next to item amount on the right side?

it should be read like this **"123 USD"** instead of **"USD 123"**

Using Prestashop 1.7 version

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be impossible in these versions. All formats depend on localizations and show up accordingly to that one which you came from. I tried to change all downloaded settings files which related to localizations but with no success, probably it updates from the internet(http://i18n.prestashop.com/cldr/json-full/) every time you clean a cache. So the only solution I found is to modify the cache directly but it is not a reliable approach. But if you want you can do this 
Go to folder `translations/cldr/` and modify a file `main--en-US--numbers` replace `"standard":"#,##0.###"` with `"standard":"##0.###,#"` inside it. But as I said it can be unreliable

Comment: thanks for the answer. Let see if it is working or not.